# Lista duplamente encadeada em C usando funcao remover

Tags: c, lista-encadeada

Alguém poderia me ajudar, pois não estou conseguindo rodar a função de **remover**, eu fiz tudo certinho, mas não estou conseguindo, não precisa me dá o código, apenas poderia me orientar o que esta de errado e como resolver. Desde já agradeço!
Vou colocar o trecho do código:

```
typedef struct ELEMENTO{
    int valor;
    struct ELEMENTO * proximo;
    struct  ELEMENTO * anterior;
}ELEMENTO;

typedef struct LISTA{
    ELEMENTO * primeiro;
    ELEMENTO * ultimo;
    int quant_elementos;
}LISTA;

void remover(LISTA * lista, int valor){
    if(list->primeiro->valor == valor){
        ELEMENTO * aux = lista->primeiro;
        lista->primeiro = lista->primeiro->proximo;
        lista->primeiro->anterior = NULL;
        free(aux);
        lista->quant_elementos--;
    }else{
        ELEMENTO * aux = lista->primeiro->proximo;
        while(aux->proximo != NULL){
            if (aux->valor == valor)
            {
                aux->anterior->proximo = aux->proximo;
                aux->proximo->anterior = aux->anterior;
                free(aux);
                lista->quant_elementos--;
                break;
            }
            aux = aux->proximo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funciona se você estiver removendo o último?

Comment: Acho que não amigo, não sei bem, ainda estou estudando!

Answer (score 1):

Substitua:

```
void remover(LISTA * lista, int valor){
    if(list->primeiro->valor == valor){
//...
```

Por:

```
void remover(LISTA * lista, int valor){
    if(lista->primeiro->valor == valor){
//...
```

Tem alguns outros problemas de lógica na sua função de remoção. Ainda falta dar suporte aos casos quando a lista está vazia, ou quando valor está no último nó, por exemplo. Porém, para fazer esse trecho compilar basta substituir `list->primeiro->valor` por `lista->primeiro->valor`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo!